# What part of a toggle anchor determines its strength?

Tags: drywall-anchor

I drilled holes and installed the plastic toggle bolt anchors only to realise that what I'm hanging is a mirror. I was thinking I'd hang the mirror off D-hooks off of screws so I installed toggle anchors. But now I just realised... what the hell are the bolts supposed to push against?

Should I start again with another method?

[image]

Comment: The mirror is about 20lbs. There are two of these up that apparently hold a couple of hundred pounds each, but I don't think they meant for one to just hang stuff off the bolts, right? You're meant to tighten the bolt AGAINST something.

Comment: @tinpanalley Your logic is correct. These anchors are meant for something to compress against it. If you hang 20 lbs on the hole, it'll rip over time and fall off.
What you CAN do though, is use two anchors across a piece of plywood, and put hooks on the plywood to hold up the mirror.

Comment: @Nelson So, the mirror is 20lb across two holes. But what you're saying is to use them to fix a piece of wood to the wall and then put the mirror up with its dhooks but onto other hooks crewed into that wood? Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: @tinpanalley Yes. Those anchors get their strength from the material squeezing the drywall. If it is just something hanging on the hole, the direction of forces are not really what the anchors are designed for and it'll just degrade over time.

Answer (score 2):

Drywall can be surprisingly strong at holding heavy weight; that is, except for those rare times when it isn't.

If you are concerned about what would happen if it fails, don't do it.

I had a heavy TV to hang on the wall, and no matter how I lined the wall bracket up with the studs, the TV would be in the wrong place, too far to the right or too far to the left.

What I did was to screw two horizontal 2×4s to two studs (vertically separated to match the vertical holes in the mounting bracket).
That way I could move the mounting bracket to the left or right so that it would hold the TV in the desired position before screwing the bracket to them.
(It also moved the TV a little farther from the wall, making it slightly less impossible to access the wire connections.)

You could do the same thing with the mirror and completely avoid any reliance on the drywall.
(Strips smaller than 2×4s should work okay for lighter weights, just remember to drill holes in the strips so that the screws don't split the wood. Or rather than two strips, use a piece of plywood.)

**Aside**: The same technique is handy in garages and storage sheds.
Mount a long 2×4 running the length of a wall, and all the hooks, brackets, etc. can be securely attached to it at whatever the most appropriate spot is rather than where there happens to be a stud.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to say though, that this isn't drywall, it's plaster.

Comment: @tinpanalley The plaster is ON something. It's not just an entire wall of plaster. That's what you're really putting the anchors on. If the wall is really just plaster, it won't even hold 1 lbs.

Comment: @Nelson It really is just plaster. They are plaster slabs that are mounted on a wood frame, studs. This is an apartment building from the late 1940s. There is only cinder block and plaster in the apartments, no drywall at all.

Comment: @tinpanalley You'll need to update your question to include the type of material. There are no anchors for plaster because it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The screw needs to draw tight in the anchor for proper hold, but that doesn't mean the object being hung has to be involved. You could put a washer on the screw followed by a short spacer (or smaller O.D. washers) so that when you tighten the screw it bears on the anchor and draws tight. Hang the mirror on the spacer and the washer will prevent it from unhooking itself.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle anchors typically have a section that flares out as a fastener is inserted, this creates friction between the anchor and the surrounding substrate (in your case, drywall). Some anchors have wings that open as a fastener is inserted and hold tight to the back of mounting surface.

Specifically, drywall anchor strength is measured by "pull out" strength, not shear. How much force is needed to pull it straight out.

I would have no issues hanging a 20 pound mirror from drywall anchors, however, if you have studs nearby that would be the preferred anchor point.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to say though, that this isn't drywall, it's plaster.

Comment: Some concept with lathe and plaster.  Lathe is typically 1/4" strips about an inch wide with a gap between the lathe strips. Again, I think this would be sufficient to hold a 20 lb mirror, if you have concerns perhaps try mounting in a different location, into some studs?

Comment: @tinpanalley Your question in the title asks where toggle anchors get their strength, I tried to answer this as simply as possible and that answer stands regardless of the substrate it is being  installed. If you have any more questions, ask away.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the toggle anchors to mount hooks and then hang the mirror on the hooks.

[image]

"Molly Hook" source DK hardware

But last time I bent up some fence wire to form the hook, alternatively you can get anchors with built-in hooks.

Alternatively you can put a short piece of metal tube on the bolt so that it sticks out when you tighten it, or put a fitting nut on it and leave some bolt thread exposed.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm going to do. Someone else suggested this to me. Just have to get one that's strong enough and I think it's the best solution. It also has to have the same 1/4" hole to match the bolt.